# web.py file upload using the built in File form

Tags: python, python-2.7, web, web.py, shutil

I'm trying to make a working file upload form using the built in input form. It works just fine with a 'static' html input form (using shutil.copyfileobject), but it won't work using the built in one.

```
import web, shutil
from web import form

urls = ('/', 'Index')

app = web.application(urls, globals())
render = web.template.render('templates/')

fileForm = form.Form(form.File('myfile'))

class Index(object):
    def GET(self):
        f = fileForm()
        return render.index(f)
    def POST(self):
        f = fileForm()
        fi = f['myfile']
        mydir = 'uploads/'
        shutil.copy(fi, mydir)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    app.run()
```

And templates/index.html

```
$def with (f)
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head> 

<title>Title</title>

</head>

<body>
<form name="main" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data" action="">
$:f.render()
<input type="submit">
</form>
</body>

</html>
```

Errors:

```
<type 'exceptions.TypeError'> at /

coercing to Unicode: need string or buffer, File found


Python
C:\Python27\lib\ntpath.py in abspath, line 486 

Web
POST http://localhost:8080/ 


Traceback (innermost first)
C:\Python27\lib\ntpath.py in abspath 
479.
480.else:  # use native Windows method on Windows
481.    def abspath(path):
482.        """Return the absolute version of a path."""
483.
484.        if path: # Empty path must return current working directory.
485.            try:
486.                path = _getfullpathname(path) ...
487.            except WindowsError:
488.                pass # Bad path - return unchanged.
489.        elif isinstance(path, unicode):
490.            path = os.getcwdu()
491.        else:
492.            path = os.getcwd()
```

The built in File doesn't seem to return an object, so shutil.copyfileobject does not seem to work.

Please help me sort it out.

Comment: You put `form.Form(form.File('myfile'))`: did you mean just `form.File('myfile')`?

Comment: Well, that's the syntax: form.Form( input form 1, input form 2). They don't talk at all about the File form on webpy.org, here's where I've found it: http://webpy.readthedocs.org/en/latest/api.html#module-web.form ........... using your version renders: File object not callable

Comment: Ah, my mistake. As a second question: `shutil.copy` expects `fi` (from `fi = f['myfile']`) to be a string (with the path to the file). Based on [this example](http://webpy.org/cookbook/fileupload), it looks like it is a File object instead.

Comment: Editing the POST method to this: `def POST(self):
  f = fileForm()
  fi = f['myfile']
  mydir = 'uploads/'
  oFile = open(mydir  + 'name.zip', 'wb')
  shutil.copyfileobj(fi, oFile)
  oFile.close()`

Comment: Renders: 
`<type 'exceptions.AttributeError'> at /

'File' object has no attribute 'read' `   ... The link that you posted covers how to make file uploading work without the built in File form, and I actually need to get it to work using the built in one, to avoid some ugly hacks.

Comment: That's not what I meant: try changing that line to `shutil.copyfileobj(fi.file, oFile)`. If that doesn't work, you could also just do `oFile.write(fi.file.read())`.

Comment: For both: File object has no attribute file; Removing file renders: File obj has no attribute read, as expected

Answer (score -1):

```
import web, shutil
from web import form

urls = ('/', 'Index')

app = web.application(urls, globals())
render = web.template.render('templates/')

fileForm = form.Form(form.File('myfile'))

class Index(object):
    def GET(self):
        f = fileForm()
        return render.index(f)

    def POST(self):
        x = web.input(myfile={})
        filedir = '/tmp/'
        if 'myfile' in x:
            filepath=x.myfile.filename.replace('\\','/')
            filename=filepath.split('/')[-1]
            fout = open(filedir +'/'+ filename,'w')
            fout.write(x.myfile.file.read())
            fout.close()

if __name__ == "__main__":
    app.run()
```